# Is there a way to know when Track Changes was turned off in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, recovery

In a shared Word document (stored in SharePoint) that multiple users are editing, someone has turned Track Changes off and it would be useful to know when it happened so that we can double check the changes since then, or even know which user did it.

Can this be done? We could use the Word desktop application, Word web application or even inspecting the contents of the docx file

Comment: if it's in SharePoint, can you open past versions to see when it's on?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes, we narrowed it down a bit with that, thanks

Comment: You can easily find all the changes if you run 'Compare' against the original doc (assuming someone has that).  If you reject all the tracked changes in the current doc and then compare with the original, you'll get all the changes made since Track Change was deactivated.  The content of those changes may point you to the person or persons who've made changes after deactivation.